# Multiple SNMP Agents using SNMP4j and Java

Tags: java, snmp4j

I'm trying to create a snmp agent simulator application, that will create multiple virtual agents with unique ip address and port. I'm trying to use snmp4jagent. But i've some exceptions can you help me ?

I extend BaseAgent class to my own class then create Multiple Instance of that class. But I cannot start More than one agent at a time ie. if One agent's status is running i cannot start another agent without stopping the running agent (Code is too heavy So i don't specify any code here) code for starting an agent is

```
public void start() throws IOException
{
    init();
    addShutdownHook();
    getServer().addContext(new OctetString("public"));
    finishInit();
    run();
    sendColdStartNotification(); 
}
```

then i register Managed objects .

Code reference :
http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/snmp/creating-snmp-agent-server-in-java-using-snmp4j/

Thanks in advance

Pramod

Comment: Provide some more details and code snippet.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.  You can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6453147/1228) this one to add details or to fix formatting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does work (as tested). Maybe you did not assign different IP addresses to your different instances. Add this to your class:

```
/**
 * The ip address of this agent.
 */
private String ipAddress;

/**
 * Initializes the transport mappings (ports) to be used by the agent.
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 */ 
protected void initTransportMappings() throws IOException {
    transportMappings = new TransportMapping[1];
    transportMappings[0] = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/161"));
}
```

You probably have to add the used ip addresses to your NIC. Example for Linux:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev eth0
```

Please also provide exception messages and stacktraces if you still can't start asecond agent.